# How to remove Microsoft Internet explorer's new tab outline

Tags: internet-explorer

How can I remove the dotted outline around the IE new tab?

[image: Microsoft internet explorer new tab dotted outline]

Answer (score 0):

This outline is part of the new web standards that helps to make web pages more accessible for sight impaired users.

If you click in other tab or in the a ddress bar, the outline dissapears.